# Exception in Tkinter callback_Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, runtime-error

I have been running into an issue with my company's Python program.

I am designing a program that will allow us to make a pdf straight from the program, and find the distance between 2 points (which is placed in the program in the form of 2 addresses). How can I solve the following error?

```
 Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\micae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1895, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/micae/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 271, in invoice_calculate
    Button(calculate_window,text="DONE!",bg="white",fg="red",height=3,width=40,command=finalize(prerpkbrkdn,prerpktotal,rpkout,spec_req,outdistance)).grid(row=14,column=3,sticky=W)
  File "C:/Users/micae/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 231, in finalize
    pdf.page2(distance_ab, "50.02 hours", total)
  File "C:/Users/micae/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 86, in page2
    self.cell(w=25.273, h=3.276, align='L', txt=distance, border=0)
  File "C:\Users\micae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 150, in wrapper
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\micae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 755, in cell
    txt2 = self._escape(txt)
  File "C:\Users\micae\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 1899, in _escape
    return s.replace('\\','\\\\').replace(')','\\)').replace('(','\\(').replace('\r','\\r')
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

The code is as follows:

```
 from tkinter import *
import requests
from fpdf import FPDF

######modules#####

class PDF(FPDF):
    def lines(self):
        pass
        #pdf_h = 297.0
        #pdf_w = 210.0
        #self.set_line_width(0.0)
        #self.line(10,pdf_h/11,pdf_w-10,pdf_h/11)

    def page1(self,Qoutenum,Date,name,email,comp_address,comp_tel,MTY,pickup_date,pickup_time,Dropoff_time,dropoff_date,Special_requirements,km,cost):
        pdf_h = 297.0
        pdf_w = 210.0
        self.set_xy(29,80)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 13)
        self.set_text_color(0,0,0)
        self.cell(w=23.914, h=4.552, align='C', txt=Date, border=0)

        self.set_xy(159, 80)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 13)
        self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
        self.cell(w=23.914, h=4.552, align='C', txt=Qoutenum, border=0)

        self.set_xy(10, 85)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 10)
        self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
        self.cell(w=50, h=35.616, align='C', txt=name, border=0)

        self.set_xy(19, 90)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 10)
        self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
        self.cell(w=50, h=35.616, align='C', txt=comp_address, border=0)

        self.set_xy(12, 95)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 10)
        self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
        self.cell(w=50, h=35.616, align='C', txt=email, border=0)

        self.set_xy(6, 100)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 10)
        self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
        self.cell(w=50, h=35.616, align='C', txt=comp_tel, border=0)



        self.set_xy(59.261, 202)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 13)
        self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
        self.cell(w=25.273, h=3.276, align='L', txt=pickup_date, border=0)

        self.set_xy(163.495, 202)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 13)
        self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
        self.cell(w=25.273, h=3.276, align='L', txt=pickup_time, border=0)

        self.set_xy(59.261, 213)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 13)
        self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
        self.cell(w=25.273, h=3.276, align='L', txt=dropoff_date, border=0)

        self.set_xy(163.495, 213)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 13)
        self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
        self.cell(w=25.273, h=3.276, align='L', txt=Dropoff_time, border=0)

        self.set_xy(15, 230)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 13)
        self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
        self.cell(w=25.273, h=3.276, align='L', txt=Special_requirements, border=0)

        self.set_xy(47.769, 266)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 13)
        self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
        self.cell(w=25.273, h=3.276, align='L', txt=MTY, border=0)



    def page2(self,distance,traveltime,total):
        self.set_xy(41.029, 11)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 13)
        self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
        self.cell(w=25.273, h=3.276, align='L', txt=distance, border=0)

        self.set_xy(159.902, 11)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 13)
        self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
        self.cell(w=25.273, h=3.276, align='L', txt=traveltime, border=0)

        self.set_xy(29.217, 87)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 13)
        self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
        self.cell(w=25.273, h=3.276, align='L', txt=total, border=0)


    def imagex(self,pic):
        self.set_xy(1, 2)
        self.image(pic, link='', type='', w=205, h=270)


    def invoice(self,invoice):
        count=0
        start_co=28.203
        text=""
        while count !=len(invoice):
            if invoice[count] == ".":
                self.set_xy(10.404, start_co)
                self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 10)
                self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
                self.cell(w=185.762, h=2.972, align='L', txt=text, border=0)
                start_co=start_co+5.1
                text=""

            text=text+invoice[count]
            count=count+1

    def paragrapgh(self,input,x,start_y):
        count = 0
        start_co=start_y
        text = ""
        while count != len(input):
            if input[count] == "," or count==len(input):
                self.set_xy(x, start_co)
                self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 10)
                self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
                self.cell(w=185.762, h=2.972, align='L', txt=text, border=0)
                start_co = start_co + 5.1
                text = ""

            text = text + input[count]
            count = count + 1

def getco_ordinates(address):
    url = "https://trueway-geocoding.p.rapidapi.com/Geocode"

    querystring = {"address":address,"language":"en"}

    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-key': "18cffff83fmshba0773be7ecca01p19c62cjsnfb676eb529bf",
        'x-rapidapi-host': "trueway-geocoding.p.rapidapi.com"
        }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    sent=response.text
    returned=findco_ordinates(sent)
    return returned

def findco_ordinates(test):
    x=test.index("location")

    count=x
    word=""
    while test[count] != "}":
        word=word+test[count]
        count+=1
    longcount=word.index(" ",55)-1
    latcount=word.index(",",25)-1
    co_ordinate=""

    for count in range(27,latcount):
        co_ordinate=co_ordinate+word[count]
    co_ordinate=co_ordinate+","

    for count in range(55,longcount):
        co_ordinate=co_ordinate+word[count]

    return co_ordinate

def co_ordinates_to_distance(pickup,dropoff):
    url = "https://trueway-matrix.p.rapidapi.com/CalculateDrivingMatrix"

    querystring = {"origins":pickup,"destinations":dropoff}

    headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-key': "18cffff83fmshba0773be7ecca01p19c62cjsnfb676eb529bf",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "trueway-matrix.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

    print(response.text)
    x=response.text
    count=31
    tester=x[count]
    distance=""
    while tester != " ":
        distance=distance+x[count]
        count=count+1
        tester=x[count]
    final=int(distance)/1000
    return final

def calculate_distance():
    pickup=pickup_address.get("1.0",'end-1c')
    dropoff=dropoff_address.get("1.0",'end-1c')
    origin=getco_ordinates(pickup)
    destination=getco_ordinates(dropoff)
    distance=co_ordinates_to_distance(origin,destination)
    return distance

def finalize(invoice_breakdown,pre_total,rpk,specialrequirements,distance_ab):
    namer=name.get()
    email=email_address.get()
    tel=tel_nr.get()
    mty=MTY.get()
    pickupadd=pickup_address.get("1.0",'end-1c')
    dropoffadd=dropoff_address.get("1.0",'end-1c')
    picktime=pickup_time.get()
    dropdate=dropoff_date.get()
    droptime=""
    special=specialrequirements

    ###workingss###
    total=pre_total+(rpk*int(distance_ab))



    ###pdf###
    pdf = PDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.page1("101","02/02/14",namer,email,"",tel,mty,pickupadd,picktime,droptime,dropdate,special,distance_ab,total)
    pdf.imagex("jsm invoice.png")
    pdf.paragrapgh(pickupadd, 19.247, 153)
    pdf.paragrapgh(dropoffadd, 110.118, 153)
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.imagex("jsm invoices2.png")
    pdf.invoice(specialrequirements)
    pdf.page2(distance_ab, "50.02 hours", total)
    pdf.output("test.pdf", "F")

def invoice_calculate():
    calculate_window=Tk()
    calculate_window.title("Invoice Calculation")
    calculate_window.geometry('1500x800')
    Label(calculate_window,text="").grid(row=0,column=0)

    Label(calculate_window,text="Invoice",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 12 bold").grid(row=1,column=0)
    Label(calculate_window,text="").grid(row=2,column=0)
    Label(calculate_window,text="Pre-R.P.K Breakdown (Use . to represent a new line)",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 10 bold").grid(row=3,column=2,sticky=W)
    Pre_rpk_breakdown=Text(calculate_window,bg="white",fg="black",width=40,height=10)
    Pre_rpk_breakdown.grid(row=4,column=3)
    prerpkbrkdn=Pre_rpk_breakdown.get("1.0",'end-1c')

    Label(calculate_window, text="").grid(row=5, column=0)
    Label(calculate_window,text="Pre-R.P.K. Total:",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 10 bold").grid(row=6,column=2,sticky=W)
    Pre_rpk_total=Entry(calculate_window,bg="white",fg="black",width=60)
    Pre_rpk_total.grid(row=6,column=3)
    prerpktotal=Pre_rpk_total.get()

    Label(calculate_window,text="").grid(row=7,column=0)
    Label(calculate_window,text="Final Total (WITH R.P.K.)",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 12 bold").grid(row=8,column=0,sticky=W)

    distance=(f"{calculate_distance()}KM Total Distance     At(R.P.K.):")
    outdistance=calculate_distance()
    Label(calculate_window,text="").grid(row=9,column=0)
    Label(calculate_window,text=distance,bg="white",fg="black",font="none 10 bold").grid(row=10,column=2,sticky=W)
    rpk=Entry(calculate_window,bg="white",fg="black",width=10)
    rpk.grid(row=10,column=3,sticky=W)
    rpkout=rpk.get()

    Label(calculate_window,text="").grid(row=11,column=0)
    Label(calculate_window,text="Special Requirements",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 10 bold").grid(row=12,column=2,sticky=W)
    special_requirements=Text(calculate_window,bg="white",fg="black",width=40,height=10)
    special_requirements.grid(row=12,column=3,sticky=W)
    spec_req=special_requirements.get("1.0",'end-1c')

    Label(calculate_window,text="").grid(row=13,column=0)
    Button(calculate_window,text="DONE!",bg="white",fg="red",height=3,width=40,command=finalize(prerpkbrkdn,prerpktotal,rpkout,spec_req,outdistance)).grid(row=14,column=3,sticky=W)


    calculate_window.mainloop()

window = Tk()

window.title("JSM_SOLUTIONS_INTERNAL_PROGRAM")

window.geometry('1500x800')

Label(window,text="",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)

Label(window,text="Client Info:",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 13 bold") .grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)


Label(window,text="",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 12 bold") .grid(row=3,column=2,sticky=W)


Label(window,text=" Name:",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 10 bold") .grid(row=4,column=2,sticky=W)

name=Entry(window,width=40,bg="white")
name.grid(row=4,column=3)

Label(window,text="",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 10 bold") .grid(row=5,column=2,sticky=W)

Label(window,text=" Email Address:",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 10 bold") .grid(row=6,column=2,sticky=W)

email_address=Entry(window,width=40,bg="white")
email_address.grid(row=6,column=3)

Label(window,text="").grid(row=7,column=2)
Label(window,text=" Telephone Number:",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 10 bold").grid(row=8,column=2,sticky=W)

tel_nr=Entry(window,fg="black",width=40,bg="white")
tel_nr.grid(row=8,column=3)

Label(window,text="").grid(row=9,column=0)
Label(window,text="Pickup and Drop-off info:",bg="white",fg="black",font=("none 13 bold")).grid(row=10,column=0)

Label(window,text="Pickup Address:",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 10 bold").grid(row=11,column=2)
pickup_address=Text(window,bg="white",fg="black",height=6,width=30)
pickup_address.grid(row=12,column=2)

Label(window,text="Dropoff Address:",fg="black",bg="white",font="none 10 bold").grid(row=11,column=3)
dropoff_address=Text(window,fg="black",bg="white",width=30,height=6)
dropoff_address.grid(row=12,column=3)

Label(window,text="").grid(row=13,column=0)

Label(window,text="Pickup Date:",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 10 bold").grid(row=14,column=2,sticky=W)
pickup_date=Entry(window,bg="white",fg="black",width=40)
pickup_date.grid(row=14,column=3)

Label(window,text="").grid(row=15,column=0)

Label(window,text="Pickup Time:",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 10 bold").grid(row=16,column=2,sticky=W)
pickup_time=Entry(window,bg="white",fg="black",width=40)
pickup_time.grid(row=16,column=3)

Label(window,text="").grid(row=17,column=0)

Label(window,text="Dropoff Date:",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 10 bold").grid(row=18,column=2,sticky=W)
dropoff_date=Entry(window,bg="white",fg="black",width=40)
dropoff_date.grid(row=18,column=3)

Label(window,text="").grid(row=19,column=0)
Label(window,text="MTY Depot:",bg="white",fg="black",font="none 10 bold").grid(row=20,column=2,sticky=W)
MTY=Entry(window,bg="white",fg="black",width=40)
MTY.grid(row=20,column=3)

Label(window,text="").grid(row=21,column=0)
Button(window,text="CALCULATE!",bg="white",fg="red",width=80,height=2,command=invoice_calculate).grid(row=22,column=3)

#####################program starts######################
window.mainloop()
```

I am reasonably sure that this may be a logic issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because you are passing a float as the argument for `txt`. I assume it is expecting a string, so change `txt = distance` to `txt = str(distance)` and it should work.
Here's the modified code:

```
def page2(self,distance,traveltime,total):
        self.set_xy(41.029, 11)
        self.set_font('Arial', 'B', 13)
        self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
        self.cell(w=25.273, h=3.276, align='L', txt=str(distance), border=0)
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If this resolved your problem, please accept this answer with the check mark button.